# Batch File - Add new line instead of overwriting file

Tags: batch-file

I create a simple Batch File - Insert text.

```
@echo off

set /p title="Enter Title: "
set /p username="Enter username: "
set /p password="Enter password: "

echo %title% > credentials.txt
echo %password%>>credentials.txt
echo ==========>>credentials.txt
cls
```

My problem is that every time I run the program, the code deletes the text in file and overwrites it with the new text. But I want to save everything, old and new.

Comment: Change your `echo %title%` line to also use `>>` instead of `>`. Using `>>` appends instead of overwriting.

Comment: Never occurred to you that one > symbol was different than two?